# binary operator cannot be applied to operands

Tags: swift2

Recently, i am reading "functional programming in swift". In the book, the author does some extension of Int to meet a protocol `Smaller`. In order to get a thorough understanding of the author's idea, i copy the code to my own playground, but it reports error.

```
protocol Smaller {
    static func smaller() -> Self?
}

extension Int: Smaller {
    static func smaller() -> Int? {
      //reporting error: Binary operator "==" cann't be applied to type of Int.type and Int  
      return self == 0 ? nil : self / 2
    }
}
```

it seems that `self == 0` is not allowed in the extension. Does anybody have an idea of the reason.

Comment: I don't know swift, but why is the signature of the method different in the protocol and extension (return type)?

Comment: that is the rule for swift protocol, Self has to be replaced by the type itself.

Comment: In a `static` method, the keyword `self` refers to the type, not the an actual instance, so you should not use `static`, since it looks like that you want to work with instances of `Int`

Comment: oh yeah, i think you are right. Thanks very much.

Comment: can you make your comment an answer, i will adopt it.@DánielNagy

Comment: @trojanfoe I am very sorry that what i have told you about the `Self` of swift protocol is not quite correct.  After the deep learning about `Self` recently, i find that the `Self` has to be replaced by the type itself just in the case of `struct` which can't be inherited. But in the case of `class`, the `Self` can't be changed to anything else. It mainly due to the reason that `class` can be inherited, and the `Self` refers to the `class` itself and its subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you wanted to use a static function as you need a instantiated integer to work on and check if it is smaller.

So there are 2 approaches:

- Remove the static from the function and then call it normally:

  `let aInt = 4
  aInt.smaller() //will be 2`
- or you change the signature of the static function to accept the instance as an argument

`

```
protocol Smaller {
  static func smaller(selfToMakeSmall: Self) -> Self?
}

extension Int: Smaller {
  static func smaller(selfToMakeSmall: Int) -> Int? {
    //reporting error: Binary operator "==" cann't be applied to type of Int.type and Int
    return selfToMakeSmall == 0 ? nil : selfToMakeSmall / 2
  }
}


let theInt = 4
Int.smaller(theInt)
```

`

but I think this could be also improved with Generics